# Similarity metric with an MDX query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have an SSAS cube containing time allocation data for an organization and I'd like to create a metric to find out how similarly time is allocated between departments, units and persons.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume there are two hierarchies and a measure:

- Organization: [Department].[Unit].[Person] and
- WorkType: [Process].[Activity].[Code].
- Measures.HoursAllocated

Let's also suppose it's a good idea to use the Euclidean distance as a metric. I.e I'd like to calculate something like

```
SQRT(
    SUM(
      (HoursAllocated(<Organisation member>,<Worktype>)-
       HoursAllocated(<Another organisation member>,<Worktype>)
      )^2)
))
```

for a cartesian self join of the Organization hierarchy. The results should look something like (assuming we're comparing persons)

```
Person A    Person B    similarity
----------------------------------
Jamie       Jamie       1.0                
            Tyrion      0.5
            Cersei      0.9
Tyrion      Jamie       0.5
            Tyrion      1.0
            Cersei      0.2
```

I have no idea how to query this. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If we do the following in `mdx` :

```
WITH 
  SET [setA] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer] 
  SET [setB] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer] 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,
  [setA] * [setB] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

We get this error:

> Query (9, 3) The Customer hierarchy is used more than once in the
>   Crossjoin function.

Cube design isn't what I do, but I suspect you will need to change the cube structure.
Can you create a second `[Department].[Unit].[Person]` dimension?